# ¿Por qué no está traducido el Código de Conducta?

Tags: discusión, soporte, bug

A partir de [un comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/606695/javascript-todas-las-combinaciones-de-numeros-y-letras-posibles#comment1070408_606695) que dejé en [una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/606695/16597), recibí a modo respuesta del OP [un comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/606695/javascript-todas-las-combinaciones-de-numeros-y-letras-posibles#comment1070411_606695) (*en mi opinión*) fuera de lugar.

Esto me llevó a buscar el ["Código de Conducta"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/conduct) el cual veo que **no está traducido**.

¿Se podrá traducir al español?

Comment: Pues...tienes toda la razón. He mirado en [traducir](https://es.traducir.win/) y si que hay varias cadenas del codigo de conducta disponibles para traducir. He traducido alguna, a ver si se obtienen de ahi o hay que traducir la página de otro lado. Si es este ultimo caso, lo consultaremos.

Comment: Me quedé con ganas de leer el comentario xD

Comment: El comentario de ese usuario era directamente un insulto, no entiendo porque no hubo ban. Además que el nombre que utiliza considero que tampoco es adecuado

Comment: Realmente en [traducir](https://es.traducir.win) hay varias cadenas pendientes de traducción (además, me parece que [esta sección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/conduct/abusive-behavior) no existía anteriormente). Lo que me llama la atención es que las que sí están traducidas aún no aparecen en el CdC.

Comment: Hay muchas cadena por traducir.. y otras que hay que aprobar.. asi que de a poco estoy en eso...